# Convert text to columns issue with date format MMM-YY

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a conversion using text to columns in Excel on a text like:

```
NAME|PERIOD_NAME|AMOUNT|CREATION_DATE
ANDY|OCT-18|6385.46|17-OCT-2018
```

I'm using the following code

```
Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _ 
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
```

The problem is that the output on the dates with format MMM-YY turns like YY-MMM-YY

[image: Date format]

Any ideas on what is causing the issue or how can the VBA code be formatted to correct this issue?

Comment: Is `OCT-18` supposed to be `01-OCT-2018`?

Comment: Yes, I need it as the 1st day of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the parameters for .textToColumns is `dataType` in which you can set all the parsed data to a string or integer or whatever you choose, and in this case Excel is automatically converting a string to a date. To specify a different data type for each column, you create an array of delimited dataTypes that correspond to each field. They're enumerated here on [Microsoft's VBA page here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @oxwilder, that helped. I've used ,FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, xlTextFormat)) and it works. It seems like I don't need to add all the arrays as fields there is, but I do need to add the ones before the field I need to modify. Is this correct?

Comment: Ah, that would make sense since it probably just takes the default dataType for the remaining columns. Glad it worked!